# Apache Ignite Yarn Deployment HDFS issue

Tags: ignite

I am trying out Apache Ignite yarn deployment https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/yarn-deployment. When i run the below yarn jar command, i am facing HDFS access issue.

```
yarn jar ignite-yarn-2.7.0.jar ./ignite-yarn-2.7.0.jar cluster.properties
```

cluster.properties

```
IGNITE_NODE_COUNT=2
   IGNITE_RUN_CPU_PER_NODE=1
   IGNITE_MEMORY_PER_NODE=2048
   IGNITE_PATH=/project/ignite/apache-ignite- 
 2.7.0-bin.zip
   IGNITE_VERSION=2.7.0
   IGNITE_WORK_DIR=/project/ignite/workdir/
```

When i have configured IGNITE_WORK_DIR path, why HDFS still  tries to access the root directory?

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=m0143821, access=WRITE, inode="/":hdfs:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
                at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.checkFsPermission(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:279)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.check(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:260)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.check(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:240)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.checkPermission(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:162)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:152)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:3529)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:3512)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkAncestorAccess(FSDirectory.java:3494)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkAncestorAccess(FSNamesystem.java:6599)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2821)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInt(FSNamesystem.java:2739)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFile(FSNamesystem.java:2624)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.create(NameNodeRpcServer.java:599)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.create(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:112)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.create(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:401)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
            at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:617)
            at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1073)
            at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2216)
            at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2212)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
            at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1920)
            at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2210)

            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
            at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:73)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.newStreamForCreate(DFSOutputStream.java:2052)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.create(DFSClient.java:1759)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.create(DFSClient.java:1683)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$7.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:425)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$7.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:421)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.create(DistributedFileSystem.java:421)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.create(DistributedFileSystem.java:362)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:925)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:906)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:803)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:368)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:341)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(FileSystem.java:2042)
            at org.apache.ignite.yarn.utils.IgniteYarnUtils.copyLocalToHdfs(IgniteYarnUtils.java:86)
            at org.apache.ignite.yarn.IgniteYarnClient.main(IgniteYarnClient.java:89)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Comment: The issue is resolved now. Though the documentation says the property name to set ignite working dir is IGNITE_WORK_DIR, but the the source code has the property name as IGNITE_WORKING_DIR. Once change the property name to IGNITE_WORK_DIR my application started running.

Comment: Thank you for noticing? Is this the page: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/IGNITE/YARN+Integration I have updated it

Comment: I don't have access to the link you have shared. I was referring to the following link https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/yarn-deployment for my poc.

Comment: Thank you, I have fixed this one also.

Comment: I have another question, Is there any way we can set the yarn queue instead of yarn application starting under default queue. I looked at the source code of IgniteYarnClient. Queue is set to default, and i Couldn't find any property which can override it from yarn ignite deployment documentation.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you can't. Consider contributing to Ignite!

Comment: Sure, Alamar. Is this the link i should follow to contribute? https://ignite.apache.org/community/contribute.html

Comment: That is correct.